# Example of absolute convergent series divergent

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

I have learnt that in complete norm space any series that is absolute convergent is convergent.

However, I am wondering is there any example of divergent series which is absolute convergent in that norm space.

Thanks

Comment: Then you have learned something that is NOT true.  The set of all real numbers is a complete normed space.  The sequence {3, -3, 3, -3, 3, ..,}

Comment: @user247327 he said **series**.

Answer (score -1):

You said it yourself, if a series converges absolutely then the series converges. So you cannot have a divergent series that converges absolutely.

Comment: Actually, this is not true if the space in question is non-complete.